# Git repository stopped syncing Azure local, instead used Azure cloud in Visual Studio, need to move back to local

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have source control enabled in Visual Studio 2019 using Git.  I had been checking in the solution (which is in a Git repository locally) to my on premise Azure Dev Ops server.  Somewhere along the line I noticed that my on premise Azure commits were no longer there, but instead, somehow got changed to my Azure Cloud account.  The login to my Azure cloud account is the same as my AD account for on prem.  If I change the URL in the repository settings to sync (push) to the on prem server, I get an error that remote does not match local.

Is the only way to get the on premise Azure solution synced back up to delete and start fresh as if it were a new source control?

Answer (score 0):

You can check in Team Explorer whether you choose to connect to the repo on Azure Devops Server.

[image]

Comment: When I choose to connect to the local Azure Dev Ops server, it closes my solution and requires me to clone from the server.  This would be code from when things started connecting to the cloud instead and not the latest from the other cloud server.  I need to find a way to merge the 2 repositories.

Comment: As workaround , you can use `git remote add onpremise {server repo url}`,then `git push onpremise master`. Or use `git remote set-url origin {server repo url}`

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.